# How to highlight or change the color of some words in a label dynamically at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a label containing some text and I want to highlight or change the color of some words in the text of the label and not all of the words. It has to be dynamic. Any suggestions?

It's for c# with ASP.NET in a user control in webpart in sharepoint

Comment: is this winforms, asp.net, etc?

Comment: Also, does it need to be done dynamically?  Do you need to be able to vary the words that are being changed?  Does the text change?  Lot of variables here...might be easiest to give some examples of what you're looking for.

Comment: sorry for not being specific but I need it dynamic to change during runtime

Comment: It's better to update the original question instead of opening a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178249/how-to-highlight-or-change-the-color-of-some-words-in-a-label

Comment: i did but no one replied back because it got old

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.  Those questions were posted only seven minutes apart.

Comment: @Ahmad - please give users a chance to answer instead of starting a new question. Opening duplicate questions is not good user etiquette, particularly if users put the time in to give a more complete answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the server-side, you could just embed some Html in your Label's text (VB):

```
myLabel.Text="Some normal text <span style='color: red;'>some red text</span>"
```

That's the basic mechanism, but 'dynamic' could mean a lot of things here. If you post some more details about exactly what you're doing, I might be able to help more.

One more thought: as Rob Allen pointed out, the Literal control may be a slightly better choice in this situation since it's intended to emit raw Html, whereas the Label  wraps the text in a span so that the whole thing can be formatted easily.

Check this out for more details: [StackOverflow: Literals versus Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510998/what-literal-control-is-used-for-in-asp-net-and-difference-between-it-and-label)

For the record, depending on the situation I think a Label may actually be okay here.

Comment: This would work a bit better in a `Literal` instead of a `Label` and also make more sense semantically

Answer (score 7):

For ASP.NET,

wrap the words you want highlighted in a `<span>`. Then set the `<span>` style `background-color` to the colour of your choice, or use a CSS class to do so.

For example,

```
<asp:Label runat="server">
    <span style="background-color:Blue;">Hello</span> World
</asp:Label>
```

or

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="<span style='background-color:Blue;'>Hello</span> World" />
```

**EDIT:**

If setting this in code behind, then you can do something like the following

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 builder.Append([start of text]);
 builder.Append("<span style=\"background-color:Blue;\">");
 builder.Append([text to highlight]);
 builder.Append("</span>");
 builder.Append([rest of text]);

 Label.Text = builder.ToString();
```

If you needed to match text already in the label against some specific text then something like the following

```
 string theTextToMatch = "[Text to match]";
 string theText = Label.Text;

 int leftIndex = theText.IndexOf(theTextToMatch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
 int rightIndex = leftIndex + theTextToMatch.Trim().Length;

 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 builder.Append(theText , 0, leftIndex);
 builder.Append("<span style=\"background-color:Blue;\">");
 builder.Append(theText, leftIndex, rightIndex - leftIndex);
 builder.Append("</span>");
 builder.Append(theText, rightIndex, theText.Length - rightIndex);

 Label.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: sorry for not being specific but I need it dynamic to change during runtime

Answer (score 2):

I made a function to look up words in a text string and highlight them with color, the result is put into a label.

```
Function Remarcar(ByVal palabra As String, ByVal texto As String) As String

    Dim textoNuevo As String = String.Empty

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(palabra) Then
        Dim split As String() = texto.Split(New Char() {" "c})

        For Each str As String In split
            If str.ToLower.Contains(palabra.ToLower) Then

                Dim a As String = String.Empty
                Dim b As Int32

                For i = 0 To str.Length
                    If str.ToLower.Substring(i, palabra.Length) = palabra.ToLower Then
                        a = str.Substring(i, palabra.Length)
                        b = i
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

                textoNuevo &= str & " "

                textoNuevo = textoNuevo.Replace(str.Substring(b, palabra.Length), "<span style=""background-color:Yellow;"">" & a & "</span>")
            Else
                textoNuevo &= str & " "
            End If
        Next
    Else
        textoNuevo = texto
    End If

    Return textoNuevo
End Function





        Dim texto As String = "I made a function to look up words in a text string and highlight them with color, the result is put into a label."

        Label1.Text = Remarcar("highlight", texto)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to be a lot more specific. What language is this in? Are you building an ASP.NET web site with C# code-behind? Is this label in a Windows Form? Please provide as much detail as you can, and update the tags on your post as well.

Comment: yeah c# with ASP.NET in a user control in webpart in sharepoint

Answer (score 1):

Starting with:

```
<label> She sells sea shells by the sea shore </label>
```

We want "sells sea" to be red, and "the sea shore" to be highlighted.

```
<label> She <font color="red">sea shells</font> by <font style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow">the sea shore</font></label>
```

All done!

Comment: Didn't notice the .net tag. Should be asp:label rather then straight html label.

Comment: sorry for not being specific but I need it dynamic to change during runtime

Answer (score 0):

If it is asp.net (since you didn't specify) you are referring to you are going have to embed the words you want to highlight in another label.

```
    <asp:label runat="server" id="nonRed">some text 
        <asp:label runat="server" id="redText" style="color:Red">Red Text</asp:label>
   </asp:label>
```

Comment: Nested labels?  Does that work?  I think that's not ideal, even if it works.  Imagine the case where they have like you have, but "some text" followed by "red text" followed by "some text", both "some text"s in the outer label.  What happens when they replace the text for that outer label?  How do they realign "red text" into the right place.  I dunno.  Just gives me the willies.

Comment: sorry for not being specific but I need it dynamic to change during runtime

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Substitution control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228212.aspx) if caching is a concern.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="">
    <asp:Substitution ID="Substitution1" runat="server" MethodName="GetDynamicLabel"/>
</asp:Label>

protected static string GetDynamicLabel( HttpContext context )
{
    return string.Format( "<span style='background-color:Blue;'>{0}</span> {1}", "Blue", "Not Blue" );
}
```