# ASP.Net: Literal vs Label

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, controls

I just wanted to hear some authorities on when and where you should use a `LITERAL` control over a `LABEL`.

As I understand it, the difference is this: A `LABEL` can be styled via the `<SPAN>` tags that are added.

I personally find the addition of `<SPAN>` tags in my HTML to be very annoying and never actually apply styles through ASP, and so `LITERAL`s seem to be what should be used most of the time... but I'm concerned there's *other* considerations or benefits to using a LABEL over it that I'm unaware of.

**Is it 100% fine to replace any `LABEL`s with `LITERAL`s, provided we're not applying styles to them? Are there NO other considerations?**

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Yep, the main difference is that `Literal` controls just render out text, but `Label` controls surround it with `<span>` tags (Unless you use the `AssociatedControlID` property, in which case a `Label` control will render a `<label>` tag).

So, labels can be styled easier, but if you're just inserting text, literals are the way to go. Literal controls also have a handy property [`Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) which governs how the text is rendered. You can have it HTML-encoded, or rendered without any changes, or have any "unsupported markup-language elements" removed.

If you're not applying any styles (e.g. by using `Label`'s `CssClass` property), it will be fine to replace `Label` controls with `Literal` controls.

Comment: So, just to be sure here, there are NO other considerations at all? I ask because you write "the main difference is...". Obviously I'm not interested in the main difference. Thanks.

Comment: @Django: Chris Marisic's answer is really important; ASP.Net `Label` controls should always be used when you want an HTML `<label>` element. Apart from that, Labels render text between `<spans>`, Literals don't, and Literals give you greater control over how the text is rendered. There are no special events on either control, and their contents can be accessed in the code-behind in exactly the same way (through the `Text` property).

Comment: CHECKBOXES!  RADIO-BUTTONS!  If you use `Label` controls, you can add the `AssociatedControlID` attribute with the ID of the checkbox or radio-button that the label is associated with.  That way you can click on the label, and the associated control will be activated.  Making the clickable target-area bigger will also make the user-interface easier to use.

Answer (score 35):

When you have code similar to

```
<asp:Label EnableViewState="false" ID="Label8" runat="server" 
        AssociatedControlID="txtEmail">Email Address:</asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

It is optimal to use a label element because it will correctly turn it into a html `label` element with the correct `for` attribute targeting your text box, so that if a user clicks on the label it automatically sets their cursor inside the text field.

Otherwise use the literal unless having the text wrapped in a `span` would be beneficial for css styling.

Answer (score 20):

[image]

To display simple text, formatted  text or HTML text as it is i will start with literal first as its lightweight and does not emit out extra SPAN tags.

See [this video](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=794237593950519) which demonstrates about those extra tags.

But we can not apply CSS on a literal , we can not add attributes like Label1.Attributes.Add to a literal. Any container oriented things can not be achieved as literal is not surrounded by a SPAN tag.

It's also sad to see lot of ASP.NET Webform guys by default choose label to display text not knowing that it generates extra SPAN tags which can make your HTML heavy if you have lot's of label.

Answer (score 3):

**Difference b/w Label and Literal Control in asp.net**

In almost all ways a Literal control is the same as a Label control. Both of these controls are used to display Text on a webform. (The Text property can be set in the HTML or in the code-behind.)

The biggest difference is that the Label control wraps the text in a `span` when rendered. Any style that is applied to the Label control, will be rendered using the `style` property of the `span`.

**For example, the following HTML**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Text="Label Text"
ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" ></asp:Label>
```

Will be rendered as

`<span id="Label1" style="color:Red;font-weight:bold;">Label Text</span>`

A Literal control doesn't output any surrounding tags, so the Text is displayed as is:

**For example, the following HTML**

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" 
Text="Literal Control Text"></asp:Literal>
```

will be rendered as

`Literal Control Text`

So if you want to apply any styles to a than use Label control otherwise use the Literal control. Because of this, the Literal control is a light weight control, when compared with the Label control.

FYI: The inheritance hierarchy for Literal control class is **(Object => Control => Literal)**, where as for the Label control, the hierarchy is **(Object => Control => WebControl=> Label)**

Comment: Literal `mode="PassThrough"`: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-aspnets-literal-control-to-its-full-potential/