# ASP.Net literal. Insert html

Tags: asp.net, html, literals

I have simple literal on my page.

```
<asp:Literal ID="litDescription" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

When I am trying to set the following text to the literal:

```
<p><div>Some Text</div></p>
```

in my browser's markup I see

```
<p></p>
    <div>Some Text</div>
<p></p>
```

Why there are two 'p' tags? I need to have

```
<p><div>Some Text</div></p>.
```

Comment: How are you trying to insert the values? Please post the code.

Comment: And why do you not try whith the "<asp:label>" ?

Comment: @Mehdi, literals are more appropriate when it's just text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309398/asp-net-literal-vs-label

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A div inside a P is invalid HTML.
I don't think .net is making the

up.
I think it comes from your browser.

Comment: +1. If you do a `View Source` you will see there are not the extra `p` tags, but you will in your "Inspector" (Chrome, FF, IE, etc). The browser is trying to fix the DOM to deal with an invalid situation.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad syntax to have a `<div>` tag inside of a `<p>` tag. It should be `<div><p>Some Text</p></div>`

in C#:

`litDescription.Text = "<div>Some Text</div>";`

However that is still bad syntax. If you are using the div to apply inline styling to a part of the `<p>` tag, use `<span>` instead of `<div>`.

`litDescription.Text = "Some Text";` is the correct html syntax.

Comment: the literal control does not wrap its contents in `<p>` tags.

Comment: My mistake. Fixed it so you can remove the -1.

Comment: Doing `litDescription.Text = "Some Text";` will just write `Some Text` on the page, with no tags. The easiest way to achieve some text inside a `span` is to use a `Label` control without setting the `AssociatedControlId` property.

Comment: This was assuming he was using incorrect syntax for a reason, such as `<p><span>Some Text</span> and some more text</p>`.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach that is more in line with the server side control structure of asp.net web forms.

```
<p><div>
<asp:Literal id=DescriptionLiteral runat="server" />
</div></p>

// c# code:
DescriptionLiteral.Text = "Some Text";
```

Note that a `<div>` tag nested within a `<p>` tag is not valid HTML markup.