# Keep the format of Multiline Textbox input stored in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, textbox

With Asp.net I have one multiline textbox to take the users' input. I am using a separate webpage to build a print friendly version of that textbox. First I stored the input from the textbox to the session, then I retrieve it from the print friendly page using "Label". I am not using textbox in the print friendly page because I can not control the textbox size when print. My problem is that I the text format in the previous textbox won't keep and all the text goes to one line when I use label to retrieve the text stored in the session. I tried following:

```
Session["TextBox1"].ToString().Replace(char.ConvertFromUtf32(13),"<br/>")
```

But it when there are more than two spaces entered in the textbox, it will only show one space in the label.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: show what you have in `theStringYouWantToFormat` and clarify what you mean under *but not other format*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a label, try using a [literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal(v=vs.110).aspx), and have a look at this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309398/asp-net-literal-vs-label). If you are going to have to display HTML, I would use literals instead.

You need to store the HTML values you have into the session, and bind that to the literal on the print friendly page.

Comment: Be careful with literals displaying data from user-input though... XSS attacks abound there.

Comment: The user would like to apply styles when moving his HTML from one page to another - so if it is not a literal, he would need to use a string builder, and render the string to a server control.